# Azure CLI list Disk

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I want to write a bash shell script which will take VMname and Resource Group name as argument and take a snapshot backup of given VM.

Please guide me the command which can list all the disks of particular VM

I dont know Azure CLI to list disks of particular VM

Comment: Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no CLI command to list disks associated with a particular VM directly. But Azure VM just have two disk types, so you can list all disks Id associated with the VM through two CLI commands with the two types:

Data disk:

```
az vm show -d -g groupName -n vmName --query "storageProfile.dataDisks[].managedDisk.id"
```

Os disk:

```
az vm show -d -g groupName -n vmName --query "storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.id"
```

And if you want to create a snapshot from the VM, you can create it from the disks one by one through the CLI command [`az snapshot create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/snapshot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-snapshot-create).

Hope this will help you, any more question please give me the message.

Comment: That sounds great!

Comment: would be great to combine these in one JMESPath query. I couldn't figure out the syntax tho.